# Need single entry point like solution 

Tags: php, model-view-controller, .htaccess

I work on ready made framework (legacy framework).Its almost like any other MVC framwork you get in market, except that its not having single entry point.

So in every Controller file I have to include configs & Model classes.
Currently I manage with __autoload() , but still one include is left on every page.
If I add .htaccess for single entry point then I have to do lots of changes in my code.Because every controller file is different physical file.Its not even near to object oriented structure and for views smarty is used.
Is there any solution including .htaccess rules , instead of php.ini? It will be easier to maintain.
Please suggest best solutions for my dificulty.

Comment: Single entry point, .htaccess or autoload? What's your question about? Code? Need some code... ;) Update your question.

Comment: Is there any solution including .htaccess rules.

Answer (score 2):

The best suggestion I could give you is by using [auto prepend files](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file). Before any script runs, a piece of code is prepended to it.

In Apache you can set this per directory using the `php_value auto_prepend_file xxx.php` directive.

Answer (score 0):

You could route all traffic to one PHP script, usually index.php like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Then index.php would handle all necessary library files and handle the routing for the controllers.

Comment: For this I also have to change in my code & currently all my controller files are single physical file.So lots of changes will be there.

Comment: That is true, but would be easier to maintain in long run.

Comment: My first suggestion was Codeigniter , but don't know why people like legacy code and then put there effort in it.So trying to find out quickest solution.

Comment: Try Jack's solution above, never tried it myself but seems the best thing for a quick fix.

Comment: The problem with that solution is many systems are using same php , so  conflicts can happen.