# Best way to create a globally avaiable fully qualified root url and root directory path useable in both ajax and include

Tags: php, ajax, content-management-system

So I realize that there are many ways to go about this and although there are many answers on stack I can't find any that allow for a single global to be utilized for a site using ajax. Some files I have setup to allow both calls. So a if statement that checks for a $_POST['json'] and if it exists then it calls the function inside the file. Otherwise you can do an include in a file and call the function directly. The below is a quick example:

```
if (!empty($_POST['json'])) {echo json_encode(create_table());} 
function create_table(){}
```

The problem I'm having is you can't use an include ../ within the function because then if you include it that path may be invalid. I know that there is $_SERVER, $_SESSION, and of course define but they all have a down fall.

- **$_SERVER** can't be trusted if your using this for multiple platforms since you can't always trust it.
- **$_SESSION** timesout
- **define** doesn't work for ajax which would require an include which
  then defeats the purpose since you would have to do a ../ to get to
  that file but would then error out if you called the original file
  with an include to another file.

Please let me know what you think of the validity of simply say sending a ROOT_URL and ROOT_DIR as part of the params within a function? This would allow you to use define in top level pages that call others and for files that can only be called through ajax you could just use ../ to call them.

A little back history I have an employment form and couldn't figure out why randomly people couldn't submit and I realized that my save.php and encryption.php files used session variables to call the database connection. The session timed out because of how long it took for them to submit and so nothing would work. I fixed the save.php by simply making it a ../ since you can only call it with AJAX but the encryption.php file is a class that requires a include and so i ended up just allowing whomever was calling it to send a $mysqli directly which also allows different db connections to hit it in the same site (not sure why you would do that but thought it was kinda cool.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I am building this to work across both Windows and Linux simultaneously. (I run a local windows server for testing and I do my live testing on a linux box.

The below is what I currently use to allow both windows and linux to use the same setup.

```
$BASE_NAME = basename(__DIR__);
$PHP_SELF = str_replace($BASE_NAME . '/', '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$REAL_PATH = str_replace($BASE_NAME, '', __DIR__);
$URL_CHECK = (count(array_slice(explode('/', $PHP_SELF), 1, -1))) ? join( '/', array_slice(explode('/', $PHP_SELF), 1, -1)) . '/' : '';
$URL_COUNT = count(array_slice(explode('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), 1, -1));
$ROOT_URL = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . $URL_CHECK;
$ROOT_DIR = (realpath(dirname(__DIR__))) ? str_replace('\\', '/', $REAL_PATH) : $REAL_PATH;
define("ROOT_URL", $ROOT_URL);
define("ROOT_DIR", $ROOT_DIR);
```

EDIT: 
Is there anything wrong with using the $_SERVER tags for all this? Or at least the files that are running ajax and don't have access to the unique?

Comment: *"$_SERVER can't be trusted if your using this for multiple platforms"* - Why?

Comment: *"$_SESSION timesout"* - Whut? Why? What do you mean?

Comment: $_SESSION times out after a certain period which is set by the server.

Comment: $_SERVER although rarely does allow you to manually set the paths in .ini or the other file and therefore could technically be changed and then your current url and or filepath would not be wrong. Or am I just crazy.

Comment: I think $_SERVER is pretty reliable. That is, within your script it's just a variable, so *you* can change it in your script. Also, if the server would be configured to deliberately mess up this superglobal, maybe you should talk to the system administrator. :) But honestly, I don't think it's possible to configure that in php.ini.

Comment: `$_SESSION` is just a variable that contains session information. The session information itself is stored by PHP and will indeed timeout after a specific time (which is usually quite long). But it won't timeout during a request. And anyway, I don't see how it would help. $_SESSION doesn't contain relevant path information. It only contains what you stored in it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correcty, you are having trouble translating relative paths in the page to an absolute file path on the server.

To fix this, your website will need one small piece of information, which is the document root of the site.

For instance, if your index.php is in 'C:\Sites\MySite\www\index.php', then 'C:\Sites\MySite\www\' is probably your root. You can store that value in a `define` in PHP. Then, when a user tells you to include 'admin/anyfile', you append that to your document root path, effectively including 'C:\Sites\MySite\www\admin/anyfile'.

If your site runs on Linux, you can still use the same trick.

That way, all your code will be cross platform, and could even be installed multiple times in separate directories on the same server. All you need to do is create a small piece of configuration that you change each time and include with each request. But that's not odd, almost every site has some kind of `config.php` which contains settings like this.

Don't worry about the difference between `/` and `\`. Both web and Linux use `/` and Windows is smart enough to understand both.

Comment: OK I understand the use of the config.php but how does this work for a file that can be called by both ajax and include? If you have it called by ajax it would need to have its own include config.php within itself but if its called with include to another file which also has its own call to include then the ajax version would error out.

Comment: You can use `require_once` to include the config. That way, you can call it from every file. The first time it is actually included. Following calls are ignored.

Comment: Ok so your saying that if I do require_once ../php/config.php within a function and then include ../test/test.php within another file wherein a call to config.php is made by say doing ../../php/config.php the original ../php/config.php won't be broken at this point and error out the page? Additionally since its a function the ../../php/config.php would have to be global or define for the function to be allowed to utilize the information within config.php

Comment: Also, I would recommend you read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178941/need-single-entry-point-like-solution) and both its answers. It's about introducing the same behaviour to all files or to guide all traffic through a single file. The latter is what many sites like MediaWiki and Wordpress do, while the first is something you may benefit from in your current website, without having to change a lot of code.

Comment: Good idea sadly I already do that my main crux is that I utilize ajax and that works fine but then I have a few files that can both be called by ajax and be utilized as a standalone included function that solution doesn't account for an ajax page which isn't ever connecting to the original file everyone goes through

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is what I came up with that works in both linux and windows without any additional help. Also this can be set at the root level and will find the root path regardless of where you include it.

```
$URL_ROOT = array_shift(array_slice(explode('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), 1, -1));
$URL_CHECK = ($URL_ROOT == basename(__DIR__)) ? $URL_ROOT . '/' : '';
define("ROOT_URL", 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . $URL_CHECK);
define("ROOT_DIR", (realpath(dirname(__DIR__))) ? str_replace('\\', '/', realpath(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/' : realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/');
```